# Add New Field to Object in MongoDB Document

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection in my MongoDB with thousands of documents.
Each document looks like this currently :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "FIELD1" : {
        "STR1" : "some text",
        "STR2" : "some text",
        "STR3" : "some text",
        "STR4" : "some text"
    },
    "FIELD2" : "some text"
}
```

With the following code snippet, I managed to add a new field to ALL 4000+ documents:

```
// Add new field to all documents   
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject(NEW_DB_FIELD_NAME, new BasicDBObject()));
WriteResult result = coll.update(query, update, true, true);
```

The documents has a new structure where `FIELD3` is an `Object`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "FIELD1" : {
        "STR1" : "some text",
        "STR2" : "some text",
        "STR3" : "some text",
        "STR4" : "some text"
    },
    "FIELD2" : "some text",
    "FIELD3" : {
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I wish to add multiple items to `FIELD3` where each item is an `Object` containing 2 `String`s:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "FIELD1" : {
        "STR1" : "some text",
        "STR2" : "some text",
        "STR3" : "some text",
        "STR4" : "some text"
    },
    "FIELD2" : "some text",
    "FIELD3" : {
        "ITEM1" : {
            "STR1" : "",
            "STR2" : ""
        },
        "ITEM2" : {
            "STR1" : "",
            "STR2" : ""
        },
        "ITEM3" : {
            "STR1" : "",
            "STR2" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried is this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject{"FIELD2","some text"};
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("FIELD3.ITEM1.STR1", "some text").append("FIELD3.ITEM1.STR2", "some text");
result = coll.update(query, update, true, false);
```

The problem is that I can only get one new item under `FIELD3`. It keeps getting replaced with the new values as I loop through the items.

Please help!

**UPDATE:**

With the help of @Explosion Pills, I have managed to add all of `ITEM1`, `ITEM2`, `ITEM3`, etc. to my newly created `FIELD3`. However, I have another issue now in that I have 'duplicate' items in which the `value` field is the same. I don't want that.

What is an elegant way of removing duplicates? Or, even better, what is an elegant way of inserting only non-duplicates?

I was not sufficiently clear earlier about the duplicate issue. Thing is, the different items must have different names, e.g. ITEM1, ITEM2, etc.; else, they replace each other. What I wish to compare is their `value`s.

Would it be better/easier if I store the data in a different structure? I am thinking if maybe FIELD3 should be changed into an `ArrayList` instead of an `Object`.
Currently, it is akin to the follow, from which I wish to remove the duplicate fruits with "WATERMELON" fields.

```
FRUITS
   > FRUIT1
       > WATERMELON
       > BIG
   > FRUIT2
       > WaTeRMeLON
       > BIG
   > FRUIT3
       > APPLE
       > SMALL
```

Please help!

Comment: I have updated my post to specify more clearly my new problem. Can you help? @Explosion Pills

Comment: Nvm! I have figured it out, haha! @Explosion Pills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my own no-duplicate issue by changing my data storage structure. In case someone is interested ...

```
// Creating an ArrayList to store all the different fruits
ArrayList<BasicDBObject> newField = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
for (...) {
    String value = "";
    String type = "";
    BasicDBObject newItem = new BasicDBObject("value", value).append("type", type);
    newField.add(newItem);
}

// Removing duplicates from ArrayList
Set<BasicDBObject> setItems = new LinkedHashSet<BasicDBObject>(newField);
newField.clear();
newField.addAll(setItems);

// Adding ArrayList of fruits into database
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("FRUITS", newField));
WriteResult result = coll.update({"_id":"1"}, update, true, false);
```

Note: Using `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet` means that the order is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/no-sql/mongo-db/how-to-insert-nested-documents-using-basicdbobject.html) says to use a separate `BasicDBObject` for each object you want to create. It's verbose, but I haven't found another way to do it.

```
BasicDBObject item1 = new BasicDBObject("STR1", "text").append("STR2", "txt");
// also for item2 and item3...

BasicDBObject field3 = new BasicDBObject("ITEM1", item1).append("ITEM2", item2);

update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("FIELD3", field3));
```

Comment: OK. Nvm. I should be able to adapt this to get what I need. Will try it out later, thank you!